Children's book about intelligent bears or maybe cats
I read this as a child, as a library book, so this would have been mid-late 1970s - the book could be older of course.
The setting was a post-human earth, where a society of intelligent bears (?) lived.
The protagonist, goes into a forbidden area, obvious to the reader as a ruined human city, where they encounter advanced technology, but also hordes of rats.
I have a possible memory of telepathic cats being involved too - but may be conflating different stories here
I had originally thought this was Andre Norton, but I have been unable to identify the book, so now I am less sure than I was.
Any help or suggestions appreciated. I remember the book as being good, and would love to re-visit - if only for the embarrassment of what my 8 or 9 year old self thought was good!
It's stuck with me for half a century, so there must be something to it!

Is the protagonist a sentient bear?

If it weren't for the bears, this could be Breed to Come by Andre Norton.

Hiero's Journey had sapient telepathic bears, ruined cities with remnant tech, and hordes of evil mutant rats/weasels/etc.  The protagonist rode a giant 'morse', a moose subtype bred for brains and stamina.

@ClaraDíazSanchez OP is uncertain about bears, so I'd say Breed to Come is a good enough fit to post as an answer.

Both of these are fantastic answers, and I think both correct! I think I have conflated both of these stories in my head to make the story I remember!

Hiero's Journey was published in 1973.  The story takes place 5000 years after The Death destroyed most of the ecosystem.  The story is framed as a fantasy adventure but clearly takes place in a post-apocalyptic North America struggling to recover from a nuclear holocaust.
The main character is Per Hiero Desteen, a warrior priest on a secret mission.  He rides a giant 'morse' named Klootz, a moose subtype bred for brains and stamina.  He and Klootz are telepathically linked.
(I've always assumed Hiero's title 'Per' descends from the French 'Père', the French word for 'Father' used to address a Catholic priest. Much of the story does take place in what was once eastern Canada.)
One of the other main characters is Gorm, a sapient, telepathic black bear.
There are radioactive ruined cities, remnant technology, mutant animals both good and evil, and humans of various types.  Psychic powers are common.
Your mention of telepathic cats is very likely a memory of The People of The Night Wind, a race of intelligent, telepathic catfolk who become allies of Hiero in the back third of the book.

I've just reread the book.  It rocks, and I've got the sequel near the top of my reading list.  More importantly, Book 3, "Hiero's Answer", has been completed by Lanier's daughter and will be released mid-October 2024.  See https://www.hachette.co.uk/titles/sterling-e-lanier/hieros-answer/9781399620604/
